# Concatenate two pandas dataframe and follow a sequence of uid

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe with the following data: (in csv)

```
#list1
poke_id,symbol
0,BTC
1,ETB
2,USDC

#list2
5,SOL
6,XRP
```

I am able to concatenate them into one dataframe using the following code:

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index = True)
df = df.reset_index(drop = True)
df['poke_id'] = df.index
df = df[['poke_id','symbol']]
```

which gives me the output: (in csv)

```
poke_id,symbol
0,BTC
1,ETB
2,USDC
3,SOL
4,XRP
```

Is there any other way to do the same. I think calling the whole data frame of ~4000 entries just to add ~100 more will be a little pointless and cumbersome. How can I make it in such a way that it picks list 1 (or dataframe 1) and picks the highest poke_id; and just does `i + 1` to the later entries in list 2.

Comment: `Is there any other way to do the same` - is some problem with your solution?

Comment: No, no problem. But I was just thinking pulling all the data will be cumbersome, so why not pick the highest poke_id and just to ```i+1```

Comment: how are pulling your data? in loop? Or something else?

Comment: From a csv file. Not sure if I should use csvwriter or Pandas.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is good, is possible simplify:

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index = True).rename_axis('poke_id').reset_index()
```

Comment: Sure, will do. Thanks. Kept it this for now as its personally easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

use indexes to get what data you want from the dataframe, although this is not effective if you want large amounts of data from the dataframe, this method allows you to take specific amounts of data from the dataframe